# How to know If user actually shared the content from our app to other app or not?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, share

I have developed [GET INSPIRED APP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kudos.get_inspired_app) where I have listed out TOP 100 inspirational quotes. I am giving users option to share any quote to other social media apps in their device.
And I want to update the SHARE COUNT according to it.

Anyone knows how to do it in Flutter App?

Thanks in advance.[Here is the Screenshot of that screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajIWn.png)

Answer (score 1):

There is no confirmed way to tell whether the user actually shared the quote to another user. What you can do is

- Check if user clicked on the share icon
- Check if `AppLifecycleState.paused` got executed and user came back to the app `AppLifecycleState.resumed` in no less than say 10s.

This is all you can do without using any server part.

Comment: Awesome Thanks. I will try to implement this and let you know what happens. Kudos 